# Where can I get raw photos of planets clicked by HST, Voyager 1 and 2, Cassini for Saturn and Galileo for Jupiter?

Tags: solar-system, data-analysis, planetary-science, image-processing, raw-data

I intend to process RAW images of planets clicked by HST,Voyager 1 and 2, Cassini and Gallileo spacecrafts using a few softwares.
I am in search of where I can get these raw images from.

Comment: Generally nasa.gov will be the authoritative source for many of these missions. After searching **site:nasa.gov unprocessed voyager images**, I stumbled across this: https://voyager.jpl.nasa.gov/mission/science/data-access/. There might be similar pages for the other missions as well.

Answer (score 2):

I think your best bet for a uniform access experience to the various datasets is the Outer Planet Unified Search (OPUS) system at the [Ring-Moon Systems Node](https://pds-rings.seti.org/) of NASA's [Planetary Data System](https://pds.nasa.gov/) which is the official repository for NASA planetary mission data.

The [OPUS link](https://opus.pds-rings.seti.org/opus/#/cols=opusid,instrument,planet,target,time1,observationduration&widgets=instrument,observationtype,target&order=time1,opusid&view=search&browse=gallery&cart_browse=gallery&startobs=1&cart_startobs=1&detail=) of the Ring-Moon System Nodes' front page will bring you to a form that looks like:

[image: Screenshot of the OPUS search screen]

For Cassini and Voyager data, you will want to tick the 'ISS' options under 'Instrument Name' as these are the Imaging Science Subsystems for the optical (I'm assuming this is what you want, rather than ultraviolet or infrared imaging). For Galileo, this will be 'SSI' (Solid State Imaging) instead. For Hubble (HST) there are a variety of instruments available that have been used over the years; the [Instrumentation](https://www.stsci.edu/hst/instrumentation) page at STSci has links to more information for the current and previous HST instruments. More detailed information about the instrument and the data processing done are at [this link](https://pds-atmospheres.nmsu.edu/data_and_services/atmospheres_data/Cassini/inst-iss.html#analyzing) for the Cassini ISS, and [here](https://pds-rings.seti.org/voyager/iss/index.html) for the Voyager ISS; I'm sure there is an information page for the Galileo SSI but it wasn't turning up easily.

For 'Observation Type', you will want to select 'Image' as the type and then you can select a specific body as the target under the third section under the 'Intended Target Name'; the plus symbols for the each planet can be unfolded to narrow down to a specific moon or the planet itself. There are additional constraints available on the left hand side if you want to narrow down by exposure time or wavelength etc. Once you have narrowed things down to how you want them, you should be able to click on the 'Browse Results' link in the top bar (which should have a much smaller number in blue than in the screenshot above) to see thumbnails and basic details of the results and "add them to cart" to download them (if you want to download the entire result set, you will want to click on the 'View Table' option in the top left which gives a "add all to cart" option.

There is a 'Getting Started' guide under the Help menu on the OPUS page and also a link to the API guide as well if you are more comfortable with programmatic access to query and download the data, which could be easier if there are large volumes of data to download. Finally, depending on your level of experience with these sorts of data, you might be interested in Emily Lakdawalla's free course on the [Basics of Digital Imaging](https://courses.planetary.org/p/imageclass).

Comment: Will JWST data of planets be also uploaded on this site?

Comment: Very likely as depositing your data in PDS is normally a condition of getting NASA planetary science grants etc but getting data into PDS format and reviewed can take a long time (~12 months; ask me how I know...). So eventually these data will show up there - in the meantime JWST (and other missions) data is available from [MAST](https://mast.stsci.edu/portal/Mashup/Clients/Mast/Portal.html)

Comment: ~12 months; ask me how I know...)
______________________________________
Sir, how do you know about the same?

Comment: Because it's 25 months since we started the process of delivering our ground-based telescope data for DART and it's still not available at [PDS Small Body Node](https://pds-smallbodies.astro.umd.edu/data_sb/missions/dart/index.shtml) yet...

Comment: Ooh, okay. Is/are there any specific site(s) which contain all images and data related to spacecraft missions that have been to asteroids and/or comets?

Comment: Also, is data for Planetary missions by Russia, available to public to process? Are there any specific site(s) for the same?

Comment: Never looked for Russian planetary science data; not really motivated to do that given the geopolitical situation

Comment: Ooh, okay. Alright Sir. Thank you so much 